# API call (python) from twitter returns Unauthorized error but works on Postman

Tags: python, twitter, postman, twitter-oauth

I recently tried getting `organic metrics` for a tweet using postman. My trial on postman was successful, I used `Oauth 1.0` for authorization. And from this example I extracted the python syntax for the API request.

The following is the sample code:

```py
import requests
url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/123456789?tweet.fields=non_public_metrics,organic_metrics"
payload={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxxxxx",oauth_token="xxxxxxxxxx",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="123432343",oauth_nonce="abcdefgh",oauth_version="1.0",oauth_signature="xxxxxxx"'
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
print(response.text)
```

However, when i try to run this as a standalone python script it returns `unauthorized error` while through postman it works. May I ask what could be the cause of this behavior?

Error:

```
{
  "title": "Unauthorized",
  "type": "about:blank",
  "status": 401,
  "detail": "Unauthorized"
}
```

Look forward to the suggestions! Thanks.

Comment: Have you verified the value you're passing in the `Authorization` header? Looks wrong to me

Comment: Thanks for the response @AbhinavMathur, these are just some valuesfor this example but for the example i am passing values generated through the dev account.

Comment: I'm not talking about the encrypted values, I'm talking about the headers like `OAuth oauth_consumer_key`, `oauth_signature_method` etc that you're using

Comment: duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71420963/how-to-get-organic-or-non-public-metrics-from-twitter-api) please do not post multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with user context on twitter API use `requests_oauthlib` class.
You can find a simple implementation below in python:

```py
consumer_key = "xxxxxxxx"
consumer_secret = "xxxxxxxxx"
access_token = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
access_token_secret = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"

from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session
params = {"ids": "123234343"}
oauth = OAuth1Session(
    consumer_key,
    client_secret=consumer_secret,
    resource_owner_key=access_token,
    resource_owner_secret=access_token_secret,
)
response = oauth.get(
    "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets", params=params
)
```

This implementation requires you to have the all the key parameters like `consumer key`, `consumer secret`, `access_token` and `access token secret`. Please visit your twitter dev page to generate all the values (if you are not sure you can follow their docs https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-1-0a/api-key-and-secret )

Thanks, hope it helps others!